# Transform Temperature into Voltage in AVR studio

Tags: c, atmega, temperature, adc, volt

I have to write a program in C, using ATmega 328p, which turns the temperature into voltage.

So far I have done this:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
unsigned int Ctemp;
unsigned int Ftemp;

int main(void)
{

ADMUX = (1<<REFS1) | (1<<REFS0) | (0<<ADLAR) | (1<<MUX3) | (0<<MUX2) | (0<<MUX1) | (0<<MUX0);

ADCSRA = (1<<ADPS2) | (1<<ADPS1) | (1<<ADEN);

ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);

while ((ADCSRA & (1<<ADSC)) != 0);

while(1)
{
    ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);

    while ((ADCSRA & (1<<ADSC)) != 0);

    Ctemp = (ADC - 247)/1.22;
    Ftemp = (Ctemp * 1.8) + 32;
}

return 1;
}
```

Can you help me to complete the conversion part?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you use `int` for the temperatures and not `double`?

Comment: No, should I use double?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Yes there is a very sound reason, namely that this is a sluggish 8 bit MCU without FPU. It is not a PC. Using `double` would be horrible.

Comment: So how will it compute .../1.22?

Comment: Turns _what_ temperature into voltage? All you seem to have is an ADC read, which is also a voltage. What this corresponds to depends on what sensor you have.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Through elementary school math. x / 1.22 =  x*100*(how many decimals you need) / 122. Floating point is never used on low end embedded systems. If you don't know jack about such systems, then you should refrain from misleading the OP.

Comment: You mean the compiler produces such code in the absence of an FPU? Fine then, but maybe all the conversion should be done explicitly that way, because you lose precision unnecessarily in the first step.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson No, you have to do it with fixed point math. Any floating point equation can be implemented in fixed point integer math, it is just a matter of how many decimals you need.

Comment: If you use floating point types in the absence of a FPU, the compiler will pull in a software library and produce horribly ineffective code, which could have been avoided by not using floating point in the first place. This is beginner-level knowledge for embedded systems.

Comment: This is a beginner-level question, isn't it?

Comment: Well... this is one of multiple reasons why beginners should absolutely _not_ program 8-bit MCUs as their first embedded project. They are multiple times harder to program in C than lets say a Cortex M4.

Comment: @Lundin Disagree, 8-Bit MCUs are great for beginners, so it easer to understand what the CPU is really doing. Easy to learn about buses, bits, addresses, interrupts ...  Changing a formula that you do not need floating point is a simple math problem.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Beginners shouldn't deal with things like 16 bit int implicit type promotion pitfalls, extended addressing modes, manual optimization to smaller types etc. In addition, all 8-bitters on the market have their own personal shortcomings: PIC stack depth, AVR Harvard issues, the whole 8051 core etc. And then of course they all have one thing in common: being horribly slow and code inefficient. 8-bit = head ache, period. The only reason to use them in the year 2018 is because you need to maintain old stuff.

Comment: @Lundin Do you know any 32 or 16 bit MCU with a tiny package, such as SOT323? The smallest 32 Bit MCU is still really big. And why waste 32 Bit when you only control 3 GPIOs?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17612/arm-controllers-in-small-packages. What do you mean "waste 32 bit"? And overall it sounds like you are rather looking for PLD logic and not a MCU...

Comment: @Lundin A beginner should learn how a CPU works, and how to write very simple Programs. It does not matter if it is slow any that there is very little RAM. Beginners should learn that a `int` has a limit (and how it affects the preprocessor), 32 bit `int`also has a limit and that there are different architectures (a x86 architecture is much much complexer than any 8-bit architecture).

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 No, beginners shouldn't need to know why code like `uint8_t u8; ... uint16_t u16 = u8 << 15;` might occasionally crash their whole program. They should be able to write code like that with no care.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170694/discussion-between-12431234123412341234123-and-lundin).

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of overstating the obvious, it seems to me that there are two basic operations here:

1) obtain temperature 
2) generate an output voltage

It appears that the OP isn’t so much hung up on numeric representation as in actually producing an analog voltage that is a function of the temperature acquired in step 1. This isn’t surprising, since most microcontrollers (328P included) don’t have analog outputs. But PWM outputs are available on the 328P, so it’s very common to simply integrate the PWM output so as to get the desired result in Step 2.